# Unable to upload sketches to Sparkfun Redboard

Tags: serial

I have two sparkfun redboards. Neither board will allow a sketch to be uploaded from the Arduino IDE.

I plug in a board and it powers on. In the Arduino software I select Tools->Port->COM4 (the only option) and Tools->Board->Arduino/Genuino Uno. Then compile and upload the Blink example. I get the following errors:

```
Sketch uses 928 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\andy\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_463875/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 12:00:53
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM4
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x5f

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

I understand that this is a fairly generic error indicating failure to communicate with the board, but I don't know what to do about it. I have various Arduino Unos and Arduino Megas and can upload sketches to them without a problem. Since it seems unlikely that both redboards are faulty (different batch numbers), I suspect a software problem relating to the ftdi-based serial comms used by the redboards.

I'm using Windows 10 x64 with Arduino IDE v1.8.5 and FTDI drivers v2.12.28.0 x64 (all latest). I've also tried another windows 10 machine and a different usb cable, with the same results.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

**Update**

I've tried using an ftdi cable to connect to the boards on pins 0 and 1. I get the same error message.

I've also tried running `avrdude` manually and varying some of the parameters. No luck with that either.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's on COM4?

Comment: @Majenko Yes. With the board connected, device manager shows the only serial port as COM4. And COM4 is the only port choice offered by the Arduino IDE.

Comment: And without the board connected com4 vanishes?

Comment: does your PC make the bum-bum-ding sound when you plug in the board?

Comment: @Majenko Yes. When I disconnect the board, COM4 vanishes from the device manager and also Tools->Ports in the Arduino IDE, and the device manager shows no serial ports and Tools->Ports is greyed out.

Comment: @dandavis Yes. And a similar but different sound when I disconnect the board.

Comment: the programmer name may be incorrect

Comment: @jsotola I've gone through the list of programmer ids supported by avrdude but none seem applicable except "arduino". Maybe "arduino-ft232r" might work but I'm not using the ISP and am not sure of the pinouts.

Comment: jumper RX and TX (pin 0&1)  .... use the serial monitor in the arduino IDE .... type anything on the keyboard and see if it echoes back .... remove jumper and try again (just to make sure that it no longer echoes)

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the loopback test and I get characters echoed back to me. Removed the jumper and echoing stopped.

Comment: I've updated the question. Tried using an ftdi cable to connect to the boards on pins 0 and 1, and also tried running avrdude manually. No luck.